# showing variable value in <p> paragraph using getElementById.innerHTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I'm trying to write a Blackjack code using Javascript, and showing the result in an HTML page. I have written the logic already, but I can't get to show the results in

paragraph by ID, using getElementById.innerHTML. I don't know how to make it right. Could you please help me with this? I'm running out of time :(. here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Welcome to Blackjack</title>
<!--<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- <script src="bj.js"></script> -->
<head>
<script>
var PlayerScore = 0;
var DealerScore = 0;
var Winner = "Nobody";
var AskAgain = true;

function random(maxValue)
{
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * maxValue) + 1;
}

function pickSuit()
{
 suit = random(4);

 if(suit == 1)
 return "Spades";

 if(suit == 2)
 return "Clubs";

 if(suit == 3)
 return "Diamonds";

 return "Hearts";
}

function cardName(card)
{
 if(card == 1)
 return "Ace";

 if(card == 11)
 return "Jack";

 if(card == 12)
 return "Queen";

 if(card == 13)
 return "King";

 return ("" + card);
}

function cardValue(card)
{
 if(card == 1)
 return 11;

 if(card > 10)
 return 10;

 return card;
}

function PickACard(strWho)
{
 card = random(13);
 suit = pickSuit();

 alert(strWho + " picked the " + cardName(card) + " of " + suit);

 return cardValue(card);
}

function Dealer()
{
 while(DealerScore < 17)
 {
 DealerScore = DealerScore + PickACard("Dealer");
 }
}

function User()
{
 PlayerScore = PlayerScore + PickACard("You");

}
function LookAtHands(Winner)
{
 if(DealerScore > 21)
 {
 alert("House busts! You win!");
 Winner = "You";
 }
 else
 if((PlayerScore > DealerScore) && (PlayerScore <= 21))
 {
 alert("You win!");
  Winner = "You";
 }
 else
 if(PlayerScore == DealerScore)
 {
 alert("Push!");
  Winner = "Tie";
 }
 else
 {
 alert("House wins!");
  Winner = "House";
 }
}

Dealer();
alert("Dealer's score is: " + DealerScore);
document.getElementById('DealerScore').innerHTML = DealerScore;


User();
alert("Your score is: " + PlayerScore);
document.getElementById("DealerScore").innerHTML = "Dealer's score is: " + DealerScore;


while (AskAgain == true )
{
 var answer = confirm("Do you want to draw a card?")
 if (answer == true)
 {
  User();
  alert("Your score is: " + PlayerScore);
     document.getElementById("PlayerScore").innerHTML = "Your score is: " + PlayerScore;

  if (PlayerScore < 21)
   {AskAgain = true;}
  
  else 
   {AskAgain = false;}
 }
 else
 {
  AskAgain = false;
 }
}
LookAtHands();

 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><p>Welcome to our Blackjack Table!</p>
<p id="PlayerScore">Your Score is: </p>
<p id="DealerScore">Dealer's Score is: </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem is not in `document.getElementById("PlayerScore").innerHTML = "text"`, it's in your logic

Comment: To my knowledge, since I have the PlayerScore and DealerScore variables as global, running the code      document.getElementById("PlayerScore").innerHTML = "Your score is: " + PlayerScore; should work! I don't know what's wrong with it! :(

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly How? without those lines the code works with no problem. Could you explain please?

Comment: Try this in browser's console `document.getElementById("PlayerScore").innerHTML = "text"`

Comment: getElementById() can only find elements that exist in the DOM, but your script is located before the document body so it runs before the browser knows about your elements. Try moving the script element to just before the closing `</body>` tag, that is, *after* the elements it tries to access. (Also your Blackjack algorithm is wrong, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: So what should I do? I'm not familiar with DOM yet. I've tried moving the script inside the body too, but didn't change anything

Comment: Try moving the script element to just before the closing `</body>` tag, that is, *after* the elements it tries to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nnnnnn has mentioned that your html tags are not even loaded when your JS has executed and hence the issue. Try something like below to correct the issue:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Welcome to Blackjack</title>
<!--<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- <script src="bj.js"></script> -->
<head>
<script>
var PlayerScore = 0;
var DealerScore = 0;
var Winner = "Nobody";
var AskAgain = true;

function random(maxValue)
{
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * maxValue) + 1;
}

function pickSuit()
{
 suit = random(4);

 if(suit == 1)
 return "Spades";

 if(suit == 2)
 return "Clubs";

 if(suit == 3)
 return "Diamonds";

 return "Hearts";
}

function cardName(card)
{
 if(card == 1)
 return "Ace";

 if(card == 11)
 return "Jack";

 if(card == 12)
 return "Queen";

 if(card == 13)
 return "King";

 return ("" + card);
}

function cardValue(card)
{
 if(card == 1)
 return 11;

 if(card > 10)
 return 10;

 return card;
}

function PickACard(strWho)
{
 card = random(13);
 suit = pickSuit();

 alert(strWho + " picked the " + cardName(card) + " of " + suit);

 return cardValue(card);
}

function Dealer()
{
 while(DealerScore < 17)
 {
 DealerScore = DealerScore + PickACard("Dealer");
 }
}

function User()
{
    PlayerScore = PlayerScore + PickACard("You");

}
function LookAtHands(Winner)
{
 if(DealerScore > 21)
 {
 alert("House busts! You win!");
 Winner = "You";
 }
 else
 if((PlayerScore > DealerScore) && (PlayerScore <= 21))
 {
 alert("You win!");
  Winner = "You";
 }
 else
 if(PlayerScore == DealerScore)
 {
 alert("Push!");
  Winner = "Tie";
 }
 else
 {
 alert("House wins!");
  Winner = "House";
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><p>Welcome to our Blackjack Table!</p>
<p id="PlayerScore">Your Score is: </p>
<p id="DealerScore">Dealer's Score is: </p>
</div>
<script>

Dealer();
alert("Dealer's score is: " + DealerScore);
document.getElementById('DealerScore').innerHTML = DealerScore;


User();
alert("Your score is: " + PlayerScore);
document.getElementById("DealerScore").innerHTML = "Dealer's score is: " + DealerScore;


while (AskAgain == true )
{
    var answer = confirm("Do you want to draw a card?")
    if (answer == true)
    {
        User();
        alert("Your score is: " + PlayerScore);
        document.getElementById("PlayerScore").innerHTML = "Your score is: " + PlayerScore;

        if (PlayerScore < 21)
            {AskAgain = true;}

        else 
            {AskAgain = false;}
    }
    else
    {
        AskAgain = false;
    }
}
LookAtHands();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your script is loading before the document that has the elements in it.  Enclose your script in:

```
window.onload=function() {
    //all of your JavaScript code
}
```